# Throwing errors in asynchronous functions that use type parameters

Tags: typescript

I'd like to be able to throw errors in an asynchronous function that uses type parameters. This satisfies all typing requirements:

```js
function foo<T>(bar: T): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise(() => bar);
}
```

This does not:

```js
function foo<T>(bar: T): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise(() => bar).catch((error) => throw new Error('Some error'));
}
```

The TypeScript error this causes is:

```
Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.ts(2322)
```

Here's a real-world scenario for the above situation where I repackage Axios-specific HTTP errors as something vendor neutral:

```js
async get<T>(path: string, query: Record<string, string>): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
    return this.instance
        .get(path, {
            params: query,
        })
        .then((response) => this.mapToHttpResponse(response))
        .catch((error) => throw new HttpError(error.response.status));
}
```

What's the proper way to throw errors in a function that uses type parameters?

Comment: Type of `catch` is `Promise<unknown>` and that is hwy the error. Any reason, you are doing a `catch` on the newly constructed `Promise`?

Comment: The `catch` makes no sense in the above offending code. If you simply want an error from the `Promise`, you can `reject` it with an error object.

Comment: Like for example, `return new Promise((res, rej) => ... do something....; rej(new Error('foo'))`....

Comment: I've updated the post for further clarification.

Comment: Solved it with a try/catch!

Comment: @Pieter Please make your answer an answer. Answers don't belong in the question content.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed accepting my own answer would be a no-no. I've moved the answer out of the question content into the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the minimal reproduction you gave, you should specify the generic parameter inside of the `Promise` constructor:

```
function foo<T>(bar: T): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>(() => bar).catch((error) => { throw new Error('Some error') });
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgEYCGATgFyIYCUZACkXALYwDOApplogN4CwAUIgMREWUEESRgWAd0S0GzNthw4KiALwdCRCgDoIBKBAAWylkTrb1HToihG6MyTICi5uERwByAMoMWiMwtPVQBfCgBuPhCgA)

However, it is not as simple with the case of using `axios`.  Here is what I would do with your given code.  Note the `HttpResponse` is just a simple wrapper thing I created:

```
import axios from "axios";
import type { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

type HttpResponse<T> = { foo: T };

class MyHttpWrapper {

    instance = axios.create();

    mapToHttpResponse<T>(response: AxiosResponse<T>): HttpResponse<T> {
        return { foo: response.data };
    }

    async get<T>(path: string, query: Record<string, string>): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
        return this.instance
            .get(path, {
                params: query,
            })
            .then((response) => this.mapToHttpResponse(response))
            .catch((error) => { throw new Error(error.response.status) });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've verified that this is correct. I had originally typed the `AxiosResponse` without the `<T>` in the `mapToHttpResponse` function signature. Adding it did the trick. Thanks! Out of curiosity though, _why_ does it work? Because without the `catch` chained to it, the type checker is completely fine with the absence of `<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself with a `try/catch`.

```js
async get<T>(path: string, query: Record<string, string>): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
    try {
        return await this.instance
            .get(path, {
                params: query,
            })
            .then((response) => this.mapToHttpResponse(response));
    } catch (error) {
        throw new HttpError(error.response.status);
    }
}
```